# Change the color of footnote text for long footnotes

Tags: color, footnotes, memoir, bigfoot

I want to change the color of my footnotes, but I'm running into a problem with long footnotes

I'm using `memoir` and to change the color of footnotes, I can use `\renewcommand{\foottextfont}{\color{gray}\footnotesize}`. However, with footnotes that overflow to the next page, the color disappears in the next page.

So MWE gives:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Linux Libertine O} 
\renewcommand{\foottextfont}{\color{gray}\footnotesize}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\footnote{\lipsum[2-4]}\lipsum[5]\footnote{\lipsum[6]}
\end{document}
```

gives
[image]

**Update 2:** Using the solution provided in the answer below, using the package `pdfcolfoot`, creates a new problem when there are more than two footnotes on the page. The color will overflow to the main text of the next page until the [n-2]th footmarker on the next page where n is the number of footnotes on the previous page. So when there are three footnotes, the color stops at the first maker, when there are four, it stops at the second, etc.

MWE reproducing the problem:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O} 
\usepackage{pdfcolfoot}
\renewcommand{\foottextfont}{\color{gray}\footnotesize}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\footnote{footnote 1} This works fine.\footnote{footnote 2} This creates problems.\footnote{footnote 3} This creates even more problems.\footnote{footnote 4}

\lipsum[6-7]\footnote{first footmarker on next page} More text.\footnote{second footmarker on next page} 

\lipsum[9]
\end{document}
```

Creates:
[image]

Seeing as how this problem is consistent with the number of footnotes on the previous page, it seems as it should be fixable, but I have no idea how.

Comment: Package [`pdfcolfoot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcolfoot) is designed for this situation and works with pdftex and luatex, but it seems to be incompatible with `memoir`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use `fontspec` to set a font with a color instead of using `xcolor` directly.

So the working MWE becomes:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O} 
\footmarkstyle{\color{gray}\textsuperscript{#1}}
\renewcommand{\foottextfont}{\fontspec[Color=gray,Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}\footnotesize}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]\footnote{\lipsum[2-4]}\lipsum[5]\footnote{\lipsum[6]}
\end{document}
```

Changing the font does not change the color of the footnotemarker but that is easily fixed in memoir with `\footmarkstyle`.

ADDED LATER: Two issues came up while using this solution.

The first is that in the original solution, TeX shortcuts like `--` for an en-dash did not work. To fix this, add the option `Ligatures=TeX` when calling the colored font (I added this to the MWE because I expect this to be standard desired behaviour)

The second is that colors did not work in the footnotes. For colorlinks in the `hyperref` package specifically, you can solve this by adding the following lines in the preamble:

```
    \makeatletter
    \def\HyColor@@@@UseColor#1\@nil{\addfontfeatures{Color=#1}}
    \makeatother
```

Comment: Please note that it will give problems if you want to use colors within the colored footnotes now

Answer (score 1):

Use the `pdfcolfoot` package which works with `memoir` when processed by at least `pdflatex` and `lualatex`.

```
% colfootprob.tex  SE 575204  process with pdflatex or lualatex

\documentclass[a5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdfcolfoot}
\renewcommand{\foottextfont}{\color{gray}\footnotesize}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\footnote{\lipsum[2-4]}\lipsum[5]\footnote{\lipsum[6]}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't menton this in the MWE because I didn't think it'd matter, but I'm using xelatex. I've updated the question. (Also using both `bigfoot` and `pdfcolfoot` throws an error in lualatex and pdflatex)

Comment: @cktai I can't get `xelatex` installed so I can't check what that does but I have a suspicion that it might not like the `pdfcolfoot` package as I have no recollection of complaints about using `xelatex` to process the `memoir` class.

Comment: I thought I needed xelatex for fontspec but I don't. So I switched to lualatex and now the solution works as expected.

Comment: I encountered a new problem where the colouring overflows to the text of the next page. I updated the question.